# How Do I Convert Pipe Delimited to Comma Delimited with Escaping

Tags: scala, csv, replace

I am fairly new to scala and I have the need to convert a string that is pipe delimited to one that is comma delimited, with the values wrapped in quotes and any quotes escaped by "\"

in c# i would probably do this like this

```
string st = "\"" + oldStr.Replace("\"", "\\\\\"").Replace("|", "\",\"") + "\""
```

I haven't validated that actually works but that is the basic idea behind what I am trying to do.  Is there a way to do this easily in scala?

Comment: How is the pipe character escaped in the source format?

Comment: it isn't, there is no pipes in the data that it represents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similarly:

```
val st = "\"" + oldStr.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"").replaceAll("\\|", "\",\"") + "\""
```

Could also be:

```
val st = oldStr.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"").split("\\|").mkString("\"","\",\"","\"")
```

Comment: i tried this but i am getting this error "error: value replaceAll is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]"